# Remove Transfer-Encoding:chunked in the POST request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am sending a `POST` request using the following code but the request is send in the form of chunked (`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`). I googled about the problem and it says to include the `Content-Length` but in the below code I could not figure out how could I set the `Content-Length`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, ContactInfo> addContactInfo(
                                @RequestBody Map<String, ContactInfo> ContactInfoDto) {

    ContactInfo contactInfo = ContactInfoDto.get("contact");
    if (contactInfo == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Contact not found.");
    }

    contactInfo = this.contactInfoManager.addNew(contactInfo);
    Map<String, ContactInfo> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("contact", contactInfo);

    return map;

}
```

Comment: I believe it's the **Response**, not request, which is being transferred in a chunk oriented way

Comment: @RamDuttShukla Is it the request or response you want to set the `Content-Length` on it?

Comment: @AliDehghani In response.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `ResponseEntity` to set headers explicitly. The tricky bit is figuring out how long your content actually is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, ContactInfo>> addContactInfo(@RequestBody Map<String, ContactInfo> contactInfoDto) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ContactInfo contactInfo = contactInfoDto.get("contact");
    if (contactInfo == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Contact not found.");
    }

    contactInfo = this.contactInfoManager.addNew(contactInfo);
    Map<String, ContactInfo> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("contact", contactInfo);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map).length()));
    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, ContactInfo>>(map, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Test:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/contacts/ -X POST -d '{ "contact": { "name": "foo" } }' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' && echo
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /contacts/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 32
> 
* upload completely sent off: 32 out of 32 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Application-Context: application
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 26
< Date: Fri, 10 Jun 2016 13:24:23 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"contact":{"name":"foo"}}
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, ContactInfo> addContactInfo(
                                @RequestBody Map<String, ContactInfo> ContactInfoDto,    
                                @RequestHeader(value = HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, required = true) Long contentLength
) { ... }
```

Can be used to require `Content-Length` header to be sent.
Just note that you also have to add that header in code that sends request (most of the clients do that automatically but better check)