# Spring-Boot disable transfer-coding from response header

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, http-headers, spring-rest

Problem statement - a simple RESTful service in Spring-Boot (2.0.1.RELEASE, and embedded Tomcat Server) returns response like,

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 01 May 2018 00:33:04 GMT

7d
{the-json-response-anticipated}
0
```

After a search-and-find, I found that this is caused due to the header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. Tried setting the following in `application.properties`

```
spring.http.encoding.force=false
spring.http.encoding.enabled=false
```

But, to no use. Any means to disable the same ? 
Should I write explicit code to form a header with the parameter set as`false` and set it to the header of the response ?

Comment: Why do you want to disable a `chunked` response? For large responses, `chunked` encoding is the only way to avoid *huge* buffers on the server side.

Comment: Let's say the response is short and predefined, and I want to observe if time can be cut by an upfront non-chunked response. As whoever is consuming the service has still not upgraded to modern standards and wants a reason.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by explicitly adding the `HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH` header like the below:

An example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, ContactInfo> addContactInfo(
                            @RequestBody Map<String, ContactInfo> ContactInfoDto,    
                            @RequestHeader(value = HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, required = true) Long contentLength)
{ 
    ... 
}
```

You may want to go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200216/remove-transfer-encodingchunked-in-the-post-request) answer on SO for more details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure about the mechanics, here (i.e. annotations), but yes, the proper way to avoid chunked encoding is to specify a `Content-Length` response header.

Comment: This code will require that the caller set the content-length header to use this endpoint. I believe what is being asked for here is how to change this on the response. The accepted answer in that link looks more appropriate.