How to remove Transfer-Encoding: chunking from a @RestController response?
I am writing a Spring Boot app that exposes a REST JSON API; however, some older clients cannot parse the JSON response because these numbers are present at the start and end of the response body:

After a lot of searching and testing, I have come to the conclusion that those numbers are caused by Transfer-Encoding: chunking.
I have tried setting the Transfer-Encoding header manually, however it just gets ignored.
The proposed solution is quite messy as it requires modifying all the controller methods, as such, I would like to know if anyone has a more straightforward solution.

If you have the complete response so that you know the length, you can prevent the use of chunked transfer encoding by setting the content length of the response. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37749537/636009

I would rather not have to edit all the controllers, is there not a better way?

I didn't realize that when I marked it as a duplicate, it would immediately close the question. I have voted to reopen, which has reopened the question. Now that you've found a better solution, please add it as an answer. I would gladly upvote it, and in two days you can accept your own answer. Sorry, and I'm glad you found a solution!

If a client doesn't understand Transfer-Encoding: chunked (not chunking!), then they are incorrectly claiming to support HTTP/1.1 instead of HTTP/1.0.

I have found a better solution: According to this response a ShallowEtagHeaderFilter can be registered to calculate the Content-Length of the response, effectively removing chunking.
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<?> registerFilters()
    {
        FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registration.setFilter(new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/api/*");
        return registration;
    }

